# SQL window function to count distinct month to date at a daily level

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a query that will give me a count of customerids day by day, but unique to that current month (e.g. if the customerid appeared on the 1st of the month I wouldn't want to be counting it again on the 21st).

I would like the output to be something like

| Date | Unique Customers in Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-29 | 500 |
| 2021-04-30 | 523 |
| 2021-05-01 | 45 |
| 2021-05-02 | 55 |
| 2021-05-03 | 72 |
| ... | ... |

So I have

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date) AS day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', date) AS month,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customerid)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

but I basically don't know what window function (or any other method) I need to be able to get this output?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want an additional column, then you'll need *two* window functions.  The idea is to count users the first time they appear during the month.

Your code looks like Postgres, so I'll use that syntax:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', date) AS day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', date) AS month,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) as customers_in_day,
       SUM(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', date)) as customers_in_month
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid, DATE_TRUNC('day', date) ORDER BY day) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
GROUP BY 1, 2
```